# How to find all files in C# either by their names, or by their directory names?

Tags: c#

I have a bunch of JSON files that are either names `Localization.json` or are in a directory called `Localization`.

For example:

```
/Project/Localization/En.json
/Project/Localization/Ru.json
/Project/Media/Localization.json
/Project/Blog/Localization.json
/Project/Localization.json
```

I want to get all of these files. I used:

```
Directory.GetFiles("/Projects", "*Localization*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

But this does not find `En.json` or other files that are inside a directory called Localization.

What should I do?

Comment: I think the directory is called `Localization` judging from your example, not `Localization.json`?

Comment: @Syroot, sorry, my bad. Yep, the directory is simply called `Localization`. I fixed the question.

Comment: @Bigboy try `Directory.GetFiles("/Projects", "*Localization*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)`

Comment: @letsdoit `*Localization*.*` did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, you need to do this a little more manually to ensure two-character `.json` files are returned only if they're directly inside a `Localization` directory. Here's my solution:

```cs
IEnumerable<string> GetLocalizationFileNames(string path)
{
    // Return all Localization.json files anywhere.
    foreach (string fileName in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "Localization.json",
        SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        yield return fileName;
    }

    // Return all <two-character>.json files inside Localization directories.
    foreach (string localizationDir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path, "Localization",
        SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        foreach (string fileName in Directory.EnumerateFiles(localizationDir, "??.json"))
        {
            yield return fileName;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
foreach (string fileName in GetLocalizationFileNames("Projects"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(fileName);
}
```

Comment: This is so sad. Even linux bash is smarter than C#. Stupid Microsoft.

Comment: I am, however, not sure if you can actually use `**` or similar wildcards in `Directory.EnumerateDirectories` nowadays,  when running your .NET code on Linux.